# filtering array with conditional control variables in python to create numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter, functional-programming

```
import numpy as np
    def get_positions(values, mintreshold=0.1):
        maxindex = 0
        result_row = np.zeros(np.shape((0, 0)), dtype=int)
        result = np.matrix(result_row)
        result_index = 0
        for index in xrange(len(values)):
            diff = values[maxindex] - values[index]
            if diff < 0:
                maxindex = index
            elif diff >= mintreshold:
                result[result_index, 1] = index
                result = np.vstack((result, result_row))
                result_index += 1
        return result
```

I have a function as you see, gives me the positions of given list. Simply filters it. 
So i know that `numpy.matrix` should not call like this and this cant be correct way of creating `numpy.matrix`. But with those conditional control variables such as `minindex` and `maxindex` i couldn't use `map`,`lambda`, or `filter`.

What is the correct way to create `numpy.matrix` in functional way by populating control variables ?

EDIT:
Simply i want to use something like `positions = map(get_positions, values)`

Comment: I bet there is a simple way to do what you want with `np.where` and `np.argmax`/`values.max()`.  Maybe something like `np.where(values-values.max() >= max_threshold)`.

Comment: Can you show a sample input and expect output?

Comment: I removed minindex values to clearify. 
with this method i want to get matrix of top points difference to latest minimum point. eg. 
`print get_positions([1,2,1,2,3,1])` prints `[[0 2][0 5][0 0]]`

Comment: It looks like something as simple as `a=[1,2,1,2,3,1]; np.where(a[1:]-a[:-1]<0)[0] + 1` does the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but `reduce` from `functools` can be used here to accumulate a state that depends on the "past" values of your input list. Once you calculate a list of states that correspond to each input, you can use `filter` to get rid of entries you don't want, and finally use `map` to extract the information you are after.

Also note the use of `enumarate` to inject the index to the list.

```
from functools import reduce

def calc_diff(state, val):
    max=state[-1]['max']
    diff=max-val
    if (diff<0): max=val
    state.append({'max': max, 'diff': diff})
    return state

in_list=[1,2,1,2,3,1]

states=reduce(calc_diff, in_list, [{'max': 0}])[1:]

result=list(map(lambda s: [0, s[0]], filter(lambda s: s[1]['diff']>0.1, enumerate(states))))
```

when you run this, `states` will hold

```
[{'diff': -1, 'max': 1},
 {'diff': -1, 'max': 2},
 {'diff':  1, 'max': 2},
 {'diff':  0, 'max': 2},
 {'diff': -1, 'max': 3},
 {'diff':  2, 'max': 3}]
```

And result will be `[[0, 2], [0, 5]]`. If you wish, you can append a `[0, 0]` to match your desired output in the comments.

Also make special note of the [1:] at the end of the `reduce` call that removes the initial state that I have injected.

As a final note, you can add the filter condition of threshold inside calc_diff, and avoid the filter step later, but I find this approach a little more flexible.

Comment: It also occured to me that you could change your state from `[(max1, diff1), ...]` to `(lastMax, [diff1, diff2, ...])` and avoid keeping a history of max values for the entire list.